# More than 100 results with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to get a large number of tweets about a query using Tweepy. But it does not get enough number but about 114-120 tweets.

```
query = "'***' -RT"
searched_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, count=5000, include_entities=True,tweet_mode='extended', since='2016-11-25',)
for s in searched_tweets.items():
    tweets.append(s.full_text)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetOldTweets3 library in Python. It does not have any rate limit error. 
Check out their documentation: https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/

Answer (score 0):

In Twitter, [rate limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits.html) are divided into 15-minute intervals. In 15 minutes you can send 180 requests at max. If it will send 180 requests less than 15 min, it will wait until 15 minutes are over and send requests again (if the program operates in a loop).

Comment: Thanks, @Syed but my problem is that tweepy does not get more than 120 tweets for a query while there are more than this number in Twitter.

Comment: Do you put it in infinite loop. you can see my crawlers if you need , may be they may help : https://github.com/Sy-Muzammil/Tweet-Crawlers

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in data limitation of Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were not actually more than that number tweets there with the specified query.